# In Python unit test , how to mock a function with a input parameter changed in the function

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have following Python code:

```
para={is_done: False}
def func_1(para):
    para[is_done] = func_4()

def func_2(para):
    para[is_done] = func_5()

def func_3():
    # do something here
    return

def do_something(para):
    if not para[is_done]:
        func_1(para)
    if not para[is_done]:
        func_2(para)
    if not para[is_done]:
        func_3()
```

How can I unit test the function **do_something(para)**?
The problem is that **para={is_done: False}** is a parameter for **func_1** and changed based on the func_4 returns in it. Then the **func_2(para)** will or will not be called based on the modified **is_done**. I can mock func_1 and func_2 in do_something function, but I do not know how to mock para[is_done].

In my real code, **para** is a big dictionary and is_done is just one of them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Patch `func_4` and `func_5` to control the value of `para['is_done']`.

Comment: Thank you @chepner. 

I can't patch them since I mock func_1 and func_2, so func_4 or func_5 will not be called or mocked.

Comment: You can use the `wraps` attribute to ensure that the `Mock` used for `func_1` and `func_2` still call the underlying function. If you are mocking them to avoid certain side effects, I think it's time to refactor your code.